# How can I apply faces interactively under `font-lock-mode`?

Tags: font-lock

`font-lock-mode` sets font lock for the entire buffer -- normally to provide syntax highlighting.  Sometimes though, when I'm preparing a tutorial, I want to call attention out to certain lines.  It would be great if I could underline them (`M-o u` with active region), but it has no effect with `font-lock-mode`.

How can I use or emulate `M-o` (`facemenu-keymap`) with `font-lock-mode`?

Comment: Either an overlay or text properties sounds ideal.

Comment: the font-lock-face property is used as a face if and only if font-lock-mode is active. You'll have to write your own command to apply it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the hack of using `font-lock-face` (which also means no highlighting unless font-lock is turned on), you can just use library [**Highlight**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/highlight.el)).

It lets you highlight arbitrary text in many ways, using either text properties or overlays, and its highlighting is *independent of font-lock highlighting*. IOW, it gives you an easy way to keep font lock's hands off of your highlighting. You can even save such highlighting persistently, if you like.

Comment: +1 Just out of curiosity, how does that package manage to work regardless of `font-lock-mode`? Does it just decide between `font-lock-face` and `face` depending on the situation, or is there some other trick?

Comment: @Malabarba: It uses property `font-lock-ignore` to tell font-lock: "Hands off!". Font lock should never have been allowed to, in effect, "take over" all uses of property `face`. See [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-08/msg00540.html) on emacs-devel@gnu.org, where I proposed adding this feature to Emacs.